# Elixir- Cannot save Ecto.DateTime into Postgres database, where saving Ecto.Date works

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

In a Phoenix app, I would like to save a session record to a Postgres DB, with the `expires` field being 12 hours from now. My **session** model sets the **expires** field as an `Ecto.DateTime`.

**Model**

```js
schema "sessions" do
    field :key, :string
    field :expires, Ecto.DateTime
    field :user_id, :integer

    timestamps()
  end
```

When authentication succeeds in the login controller, I construct the session object and send it to the **create** function in the **session controller**. Timex is used to determine the time 12 hours from now.

**Login Controller**

```js
{:ok, session_expiry} = Ecto.DateTime.cast(Timex.to_datetime(Timex.shift(Timex.now, hours: 12)))
# Returns {:ok, #Ecto.DateTime<2017-07-13 20:56:25.969059>}
    session_object = %{
      "key" => encrypted_auth_code,
      "expires" => session_expiry,
      "user_id" => user_id
    }
    SessionController.create(%{"data" => data = %{"type" => "session", "attributes" => session_object}})
```

**Session controller**

```js
def create(%{"data" => data = %{"type" => "session", "attributes" => _session_params}}) do
    changeset = Session.changeset(%Session{}, Params.to_attributes(data))
    IO.inspect _session_params
    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, session} ->
        IO.puts "success"
      {:error, changeset} ->
        IO.puts "failure"
    end
  end
```

In the **session controller** the line `case Repo.insert(changeset) do` throws the following error:

`no function clause matching in Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.DateTime.encode_date/1`

If I change the type of the **expires** field in the session model to `Ecto.Date` the database record is created successfully, but without the time.

What do I need to change in order to save to an Ecto.DateTime field to the DB?

Comment: What is the type of `expires` column in your database (or migration)? Maybe you used the `date` type instead of `datetime` in the migration?

Comment: I did! Thank you. Changed the ``expires`` field to type ``timestamp`` and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `Ecto.Date` works the type of the field in your database is probably `date` instead of `utc_datetime` (`timestamp` in PostgreSQL). Changing it to `utc_datetime` should fix the error. If you used migrations to create the table, you can create a new one which alters the type of the column like this:

```
def up do
  alter table(:sessions) do
    modify :expires, :utc_datetime
  end
end

def down do
  alter table(:sessions) do
    modify :expires, :date # old type here
  end
end
```